# Unable to acquire connection from the pool within configured maximum time of 60000ms. Neo4J CE 3.5.x Java driver

Tags: neo4j

apparently with no specific reason, and with nothing on neo4j logs, our application is getting this:

```
2019-01-30 14:15:08,715  WARN com.calenco.core.content3.ContentHandler:177 - Unable to acquire connection from the pool within configured maximum time of 60000ms
org.neo4j.driver.v1.exceptions.ClientException: Unable to acquire connection from the pool within configured maximum time of 60000ms
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.async.pool.ConnectionPoolImpl.processAcquisitionError(ConnectionPoolImpl.java:192)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.async.pool.ConnectionPoolImpl.lambda$acquire$0(ConnectionPoolImpl.java:89)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniHandle(CompletableFuture.java:822)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniHandle.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:797)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:474)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:1977)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.util.Futures.lambda$asCompletionStage$0(Futures.java:78)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:507)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:481)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.access$000(DefaultPromise.java:34)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise$1.run(DefaultPromise.java:431)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:403)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:463)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858)
        at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:138)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The neo4j server is still running, and answering requests to either its web browser console, or the cypher-shell CLI. Also, restarting our application re-acquires the connection to neo4j with no issue.

Our application is connecting to neo4j once when it's started and then keeps that connection open for as lunch as it's running, opening and closing sessions against that connection as needed to fulfill the received requests.

It's the 2nd time in less than a month that we see the above exception thrown.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you check to see if your file descriptor limit was hit?

Comment: According to ulimit -n, the limit is at 40000. How can I check if it was hit? Should there be something on neo4j logs? somewhere else? Thanks in advance

Comment: Found https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/230346/how-to-check-ulimit-usage and found something very strange... even if ulimit -n tells me 40000, when I check the limits with the cat /proc/PID/limits, I get this: Max open files            4096                 4096                 files

Comment: what does ulimit -Hn say?

Comment: I think your hard and soft limit should be the same cap. https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/installation/linux/tarball/#linux-open-files

Comment: Yes, they are. I've found out they were not properly set, but I don't see any exception (like file not found, or something related to files) in debug.log, however, after a closer inspection around the time of the problem I see a few of these: 2019-01-30 14:04:40.628+0000 WARN [o.n.b.t.p.HouseKeeper] Fatal error occurred when handling a client connection, remote peer unexpectedly closed connection: [id: 0x3f38b7fd, L:/127.0.0.1:20002 - R:/127.0.0.1:51582]

Comment: Do you have any performance data on the server and neo4j at the time of the issue, perhaps that might shed more light on what type of issue this is.

Comment: Can you check also that you close all your session after using them ? Perhaps you have reach the limit of the pool and it's not possible for the driver to create a new one.